# Why mongoose query with promise always goes to .then block rather than .catch

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

my User collection have one user and that is inactive but when I query to find out the user which is Exist and Active, I am using mongoose 4.x with promise (see below query) , it always goes to `.then` block and display blank array but in my understanding, it must go to `.catch()`block.

Please correct me and suggest how to write the right query.

Schema

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    gender: {type: String, enum: ['M','F'], default: 'M'},
    passwordReset: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    isActive: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

query

```
User
            .find()
            .and([{username: req.body.username}, {isActive: true}])
            .exec()
            .then( (user) => {
                    console.log('user found', user );
                    // match saved and input password
                    if (user.password === req.body.password) {
                        res.status(200).json(user);
                    } else {
                        console.log('else part', user);
                        res.status(404).send({
                            "message": "invalid credentials."
                        });
                    }
                }).catch( (err) => {
                    console.log('catch error', err);
                    res.status(404).send(err);
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error when a *valid* query yields no results, so no error is thrown. Errors are only thrown for real error conditions, like an invalid query, a connection issue, etc.

The correct way of handling this is to check if the query yielded a result:

```
User.findOne({ username: req.body.username, isActive: true }).then(user => {
  if (! user) {
    return res.status(404).send({ message: "user not found." });
  }
  ...
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('catch error', err);
  res.status(500).send(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.Do we no need to write `.exec()`?

Comment: @pro.mean it depends. `User.findOne()` doesn't return a "real" promise, but it does return a "thenable" which is usually sufficient (see [this documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises)). If you need a real promise, use `User.findOne().exec().then(...)`